# angular 2, VS 2015, router beta 2: router_1.provideRouter is not a function

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, routes

I created a simple Angular 2 app in VS 2015, but I'm getting an error with routing.  The error is "TypeError: router_1.provideRouter is not a function" in zone.js:323. I know someone had asked about this error, but they found that Gulp wasn't updating the Router lib files on the website directory to the latest.  I checked mine and Gulp is working fine, but I'm still getting the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ngcorecontacts",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  }, 
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4", 
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",


    "systemjs": "0.19.31",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.1",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.1.5",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8"
  }
}
```

System.js:

```
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'appScripts', // 'dist',
        'rxjs': 'libs/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular': 'libs/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };

    var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router',
      '@angular/router-deprecated',
      '@angular/testing',
      '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

routes.app.ts:

```
import {  provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { AboutComponent } from './menus/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './menus/home.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

boot.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './routes.app';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
    <div class="outer-outlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  // add our router directives we will be using
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code you've posted seems correct. I get your same error only when I install the old router. Please, can you check again that in package.json file in `wwwroot > lib > @angular/router`, there's actually the version: `@angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2`?

Comment: Thanks for your help robisim74.  The router in the libs folder in the project was beta 2, but IIS express must have been caching the old version of the router.  It is working now.

Comment: I am having the same issue though. Have not yet managed to resolve it.

Comment: dewwwald - Check that your client is accessing the latest router. When I was looking into this issue, the problem was always that the client was accessing the older version of the router.  For me, it was a caching problem.  For others, it was Gulp not being set up correctly.